# How far is the implementation with Oracle and the entity framework

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to NO I have to use Entity Framework with Oracle database (version is not defined).

I would like to use Code First and I have read in an article from 2012 that it is not implemented by Oracle.

1) Has that changed with latest EF 6.0.2?

2) Is there still something which should not work in latest EF 6.x you made the experience with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework 6 support is implemented in **Devart ADO.NET providers**.

Please check below mentioned article for full details (posted on October 17th, 2013).

*[**Entity Framework 6 Support for Oracle**](http://blog.devart.com/entity-framework-6-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-sqlite-and-salesforce.html)*

Comment: What about the free oracle driver for EF? I can not use commercial stuff right now.

Comment: @Pascal Unfortunately there is no free version yet.You can realize that by reading this link.https://community.oracle.com/thread/2565269

Comment: So you say Oracle has no own EF6 driver? I have to get a commercial one?

Comment: @Pascal Yes.The above link which I shared with you is Oracle's official forum.Please read it.